# Running a timer code which gets stuck at zero

Tags: c++, arduino

OK so firstly, I am VERY new to C++ as you will undoubtedly see from the code. I have been struggling with this to get it to where it is now so my apologies if it's not very good.

Ok here is what SHOULD happen.

Button 2 (downButton) is pressed to select the correct program (that works). 
Button 3 (startButton) is used to start the timer for that program (that works)
The timer is supposed to count down (also working) and when it reaches zero, display a message and then go back to the start of the switch case.

This is what I am struggling with. Firstly the timer gets to zero and does nothing else. I have tried return, goto etc without any success.

I commented out the end message function, which does work BUT still gets stuck there without exiting the function.

What I am looking for is a little help to make the timer jump back to where it was called from.

Here is the code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

int hours = 0; // start hours
int minutes = 00; //start min
int seconds = 05; //start seconds

const int buttonPin = 9;      // the pin that the pushbutton is attached to
const int ledPin    = A0;     // the pin that the LED is attached to
const int ledPin2    = A1;     // the pin that the LED is attached to

int buttonState     = 0;      // current state of the button

int WhichScreen = 0;  // This variable stores the current Screen number
boolean hasChanged = true;
const int upButton = 8;  // the number of the select pin
const int downButton = 10;  // the number of the select pin
const int startButton = 9;   // the number of the start pin


int selectState;             // the current reading from the select pin
int lastSelectState = LOW;   // the previous reading from the select pin
int backState;             // the current reading from the select pin
int lastBackState = LOW;   // the previous reading from the select pin
int startState;             // the current reading from the start pin
int lastStartState = LOW;   // the previous reading from the start pin

unsigned long lastDebounceTime = 0;  // the last time the output pin was toggled
unsigned long debounceDelay = 50;    // the debounce time; increase if the output flickers

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);  // initialize the button pin as a input
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);    // initialize the button pin as a output
  pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);    // initialize the button pin as a output
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  pinMode(upButton, INPUT);
  pinMode(startButton, INPUT);
  pinMode(downButton, INPUT);
  pinMode(A0, OUTPUT);    // LED 1
  pinMode(A1, OUTPUT);    // LED 2
  pinMode(A2, OUTPUT);    // LED 3

}
void loop()
{
start:
  // Read the SELECT pin
  if (WhichScreen == 1) {
    buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

    if (buttonState == HIGH) {

      digitalWrite(ledPin, buttonState);
      delay(2000);
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    }
  }


  if (WhichScreen == 4) {
    buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

    if (buttonState == HIGH) {

      //   digitalWrite(ledPin2, buttonState);
      //   delay(5000);
      //   digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);

      lcd.begin(16, 2);

      minutes = 00; //start min
      seconds = 05; //start seconds
      digitalWrite(ledPin, buttonState);
      lcd.print("P1-AMBER");
      timer();

// Function SHOULD return to here when reaches zero

      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
      minutes = 00; //start min
      seconds = 05; //start seconds
      lcd.print("P1-DARK RED");
      timer();
    }
  }





  if (hasChanged == true) {

    switch (WhichScreen) {

      case 0:
        {
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.setCursor(2, 0); // Column, line
          lcd.print("LIGHT THERAPY");
          lcd.setCursor(2, 1);
          lcd.print("PANEL   V1.01");
          delay(2500);    // will be removed once relays are installed
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.setCursor(4, 0); // Column, line
          lcd.print("WELCOME");
          lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
          lcd.print("GARY & TRACEY");
          delay(2500);    // will be removed once relays are installed
          WhichScreen++;
          program1();
        }
        break;

      case 1:
        {
          program1();

        }
        break;

      case 2:
        {
          program2();
        }
        break;

      case 3:
        {
          program3();
        }
        break;

      case 4:
        {
          program4();
        }
        break;

      case 5:
        {
          program5();
        }
        break;

      case 6:
        {
          program6();
        }
        break;

      case 7:
        {
          program7();
        }
        break;

      case 8:
        {
          program8();
        }
        break;

      case 9:
        {
          program9();
        }
        break;

    }
  }

  //-------------------------------
  // BEGIN of the switch debouncing code
  int reading = digitalRead(upButton);
  if (reading != lastSelectState) {
    // reset the debouncing timer
    lastDebounceTime = millis();
  }

  if ((millis() - lastDebounceTime) > debounceDelay) {
    // whatever the reading is at, it's been there for longer
    // than the debounce delay, so take it as the actual current state:

    // if the button state has changed:
    if (reading != selectState) {
      selectState = reading;

      // only toggle the LED if the new button state is HIGH
      if (selectState == HIGH) {
        hasChanged = true;
        WhichScreen++;


      }


    } else {
      hasChanged = false;
    }
  }
  lastSelectState = reading;
  // END of the switch Debouncing code
  // --------------------------------------
  if (WhichScreen > 9) {
    WhichScreen = 1;
  }
}

void program1()
{
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(1, 0); // Column, line
  lcd.print("PROGRAM 1 (P1)");
  lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
  lcd.print("14 Minutes");
}
void program2()
{
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(1, 0); // Column, line
  lcd.print("PROGRAM 2 (P2)");
  lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
  lcd.print("14 Minutes");
}
void program3()
{
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(1, 0); // Column, line
  lcd.print("PROGRAM 3 (P3)");
  lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
  lcd.print("14 Minutes");
}
void program4()
{
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(1, 0); // Column, line
  lcd.print("PROGRAM 4 (P4)");
  lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
  lcd.print("14 Minutes");
}
void program5()
{
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(1, 0); // Column, line
  lcd.print("PROGRAM 5 (P5)");
  lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
  lcd.print("14 Minutes");
}
void program6()
{
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(1, 0); // Column, line
  lcd.print("PROGRAM 6 (P6)");
  lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
  lcd.print("14 Minutes");
}
void program7()
{
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(1, 0); // Column, line
  lcd.print("PROGRAM 7 (P7)");
  lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
  lcd.print("14 Minutes");
}
void program8()
{
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(1, 0); // Column, line
  lcd.print("PROGRAM 8 (P8)");
  lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
  lcd.print("14 Minutes");
}
void program9()
{
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(1, 0); // Column, line
  lcd.print("PROGRAM 9 (P9)");
  lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
  lcd.print("14 Minutes");
}
void stepDown() {
  if (seconds > 0) {
    seconds -= 1;
  } else {
    if (minutes > 0) {
      seconds = 59;
      minutes -= 1;
    } else {
      if (hours > 0) {
        seconds = 59;
        minutes = 59;
        hours -= 1;
      } else {
        //trigger();
      }
    }
  }
}


void timer() {
  delay(150);
  while (hours > 0 || minutes > 0 || seconds >= 0) {

    lcd.setCursor(0, 2);

    //(hours < 10) ? lcd.print("0") : NULL;
    // lcd.print(hours);
    //lcd.print(":");
    lcd.print("TIME LEFT: ");
    (minutes < 10) ? lcd.print("0") : NULL;

    lcd.print(minutes);
    lcd.print(":");
    (seconds < 10) ? lcd.print("0") : NULL;
    lcd.print(seconds);
    lcd.display();
    stepDown();
    delay(1000);

  }
}

void trigger() {
  lcd.clear(); // clears the screen and buffer
  lcd.setCursor(6, 0); // set timer position on lcd for end.
  lcd.print("TIMES UP");
  lcd.setCursor(6, 1); // set timer position on lcd for end.
  lcd.print("NUMBER 4");
  delay(1000);
  lcd.display();

}
```

Sorry it's a bit messy and all over the place, I'm also sure it's not flowing very well either but it works mostly lol.

Any and all help much appreciated, and thank you in advance.

Comment: Why is this tagged "C++" if you are asking about "C"? They are *very* different languages.

Comment: Because my phone has removed the ++ for some reason. Editing now, thanks.

Comment: that `start:` should be a comment right?

Comment: It is the loop function that is executing again and again. Your `trigger` function should set up parameters for `loop`. When `stepDown` returns, the control is back to `loop` function. Then it can parse your parameters and go to where you want.

Comment: @jstuartmilne, nope, it shouldn't even be there. I was trying a goto but then decided against it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `timer` function. You have a loop condition `hours > 0 || minutes > 0 || seconds >= 0`. Since your `seconds` is always greater than 0, you have a infinite loop in `timer`.

As you can see, seconds does not decrease seconds == 0.

```
void stepDown() {
  if (seconds > 0) {
    seconds -= 1;
  } else {
    if (minutes > 0) {
      seconds = 59;
      minutes -= 1;
    } else {
      if (hours > 0) {
        seconds = 59;
        minutes = 59;
        hours -= 1;
      } else {
        //trigger();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahhhhh, I see what you mean. Poor coding there lol. Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: @user3551994 change `seconds >= 0` to `seconds > 0`

Comment: `timer` function while loop condition.

Comment: Ah so I do lol. Thank you Bruce. Now it counts to 1 and stops lol

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it solves your problem

Comment: Ah don't worry, I had a bit of code that shouldn't be there, now all works fine - thank you so much